# Structuring secret links in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, url, routes, structure, private

In a rails application I am building I have a resource called `buckets`.

I am now tasked with creating secret links for these buckets, for example -

```
http://myapp.dev/x/:secret_unique_hash_for_bucket_one/
```

- which maps to -

```
http://myapp.dev/buckets/1
```

- without exposing the the actual ID.

I also require all of the actions and subresources on this secret link to work such as -

```
http://myapp.dev/x/:secret_unique_hash_for_bucket_one/edit
http://myapp.dev/x/:secret_unique_hash_for_bucket_one/ideas/1
```

Finally I also require the url helpers (`edit_bucket_path`) to retain the secrecy of the resource ID.

How would one best structure this?

Answer (score 0):

When a bucket is created, you could hash you Bucket model attributes (or just some of them, obviously not just the id) to a SHA256 and save it with your model.
Then in your model Bucket model override the `to_param` method.

```
def to_param
  self.hashed
end
```

and then your routes will use your hashed attributes instead of defaulting to the id.

Comment: Worth noting that you since you're storing the hash, the values you're hashing it with are inconsequential. As a result, you should use a random number generator rather than (guessable) model attributes.